# Downward pointing arrow in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I'm using Google Maps V3. Regardless of my position, there's always that arrow in the screen. Does it by default add a white downward arrow in the left of the maps? I attached the image. Regardless of my position, there's always that arrow in the screen. This absolutely is not a special location.  Anyone knows how to remove it? I would really appreciate it.

[image][image]

Thanks.

Comment: That arrow is not there by default I can assure you, could you post a fiddle or some code so we can try and see where it's coming from?

Comment: What does your code look like?  That is an artifact of invalid data...

Comment: It's a part of InfoWindow, do you try to create a infoWindow somewhere?

Comment: Oh this is correct! I open a info window untentionally!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind it is I opened a info window (without any markups) unintentionally; so just remove that info window and the arrow will disappear.